# Are there any "smart"/context-aware diff/merge tools?

Tags: version-control, diff

So many times when you do a diff of two versions of a code file, the tool completely screws up understanding what's changed... you maybe move a block of code inside an extra level of braces or add an extra `...} else if {...` and suddenly it gets all out of sync.

So I wondered if any context-aware tools exist which actually try to understand the content and make smarter decisions, rather than doing a generic diff?

More usefully, can one plug such tools into VCS like git/SVN?

Comment: Try code compare by devart

Comment: I was not actually asking for a list of all such tools, more a "yes they do exist" or "yes but ..." or "no". e.g. can one modify SVN/git/etc to use a smarter tool for my C++/Java/XML files.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5372942/120163

Answer (score 3):

- [SemanticMerge](http://www.semanticmerge.com/) for C# and Java sources
- [DiffDog](http://www.altova.com/diffdog.html) is XML-aware differ|merger